# how to get only the specific return type and method names without fully qualified return types and method names in java

Tags: java, reflection

By using the following way,

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.Double");
Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method m1 : m)
System.out.println(m1);
```

the output is:

```
public boolean java.lang.Double.equals(java.lang.Object)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Double.toString(double)
public java.lang.String java.lang.Double.toString()
public int java.lang.Double.hashCode()
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
```

Where I need to make changes to get return type and method names without package name to get the desired output as:

```
public boolean equals(Object)
public static String toString(double)
public String toString()
public int hashCode()
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
```

Got the solution, by breaking the whole method into several parts, taking modifier, return type, method name and parameter name separately.

```
Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    Parameter[] param;
    int paramLen;
    for(Method m1 : m){
      System.out.print(Modifier.toString(m1.getModifiers()) + " ");
      System.out.print(m1.getReturnType().getSimpleName());
      System.out.print(" ");
      System.out.print(m1.getName() + "(");
      param = m1.getParameters();
      paramLen = param.length;
      for(Parameter param1 : param){
        System.out.print(param1.getType().getSimpleName() + " " + param1.getName());
        if(--paramLen > 0)
        System.out.print(", ");
      }
    System.out.println(")");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no built-in `toString` method for methods using simple names. The closest, I could find, is [`MethodType.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodType.html#toString()):

> Returns a string representation of the method type, of the form `"(PT0,PT1...)RT"`. The string representation of a method type is a parenthesis enclosed, comma separated list of type names, followed immediately by the return type.
>
> Each type is represented by its [simple name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()).

So, this would still need adaptation to be used for a method description.

Note you should use `Modifier.toString(m1.getModifiers() & Modifier.methodModifiers())` as suggested in [the documentation of `Modifier.toString(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#toString(int)), to filter out inappropriate bits.

Further, limit the scope of variables as far as possible, i.e. don’t declare the variables `param` and `paramLen` outside the loop but at the place of their first use. But you can also simplify the code using [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```java
for(Method m: c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner(" ");
    String access = Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers() & Modifier.methodModifiers());
    if(!access.isEmpty()) j.add(access);
    j.add(m.getReturnType().getSimpleName());
    StringJoiner argJ = new StringJoiner(", ");
    for(Class<?> cl: m.getParameterTypes()) argJ.add(cl.getSimpleName());
    System.out.println(j.add(m.getName()+"("+argJ+")"));
}
```

We can achieve the same but utilizing the `toString()` method of `MethodType` mentioned at the beginning:

```java
for(Method m: c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner(" ");
    String access = Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers() & Modifier.methodModifiers());
    if(!access.isEmpty()) j.add(access);
    String shortSig = MethodType.methodType(m.getReturnType(), m.getParameterTypes())
                                .toString();
    int split = shortSig.lastIndexOf(')') + 1;
    j.add(shortSig.substring(split)).add(m.getName()+shortSig.substring(0, split));
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Both variants only print type names, just as `Method`’s `toString()` method does. If you want to print parameter names, as your variant does, the first of this answer’s variants can be adapted:

```java
for(Method m: c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner(" ");
    String access = Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers() & Modifier.methodModifiers());
    if(!access.isEmpty()) j.add(access);
    j.add(m.getReturnType().getSimpleName());
    StringJoiner argJ = new StringJoiner(", ");
    for(Parameter p: m.getParameters())
        argJ.add(p.getType().getSimpleName()+' '+p.getName());
    System.out.println(j.add(m.getName()+"("+argJ+")"));
}
```